# Why is font name not changing? (Java FX)

Tags: java, javafx, intellij-14

I'm having a problem with a javafx label. No matter what font I type in the below font constructor, compile and run the IntelliJ project, it doesn't change the font displayed.

```
 mainLabel.setFont(new Font("Gotham",18));
```

Here is my JavaFx Program so far:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;


public class JavaFXMainWindow extends Application {


    public static void main(String args[]) {


        launch(args);
    }


    public void init() {


    }


    //Program starts here
    public void start(Stage mainStage) {

        //Setting the stage
        mainStage.setTitle("Ping Tool");
        mainStage.setResizable(false);
        mainStage.setFullScreen(false);


        //Creating the root node for all other nodes
        FlowPane rootNode = new FlowPane();


        //Setting the main scene, adding the root node to it and passing dimensions
        Scene mainScene = new Scene(rootNode, 1000, 800);

        //placing the scene on the stage
        mainStage.setScene(mainScene);

        //Setting a label ( no matter what argument I pass to the font it still 
        //shows the same font. The size argument works fine though)

        Label mainLabel = new Label("Please enter IP addresses below:");
        mainLabel.setFont(new Font("Gotham",18));

        //Adding the node to the tree
        rootNode.getChildren().addAll(mainLabel);

        //making the Stage visible
        mainStage.show();
    }


    public void stop() {


    }


}
```

Comment: It's possible that the font (by the specified name) doesn't not exist on your system (or is not installed in such away as to allow the JVM to load it). You can use `Font.getFontNames()` to list all the available font names, I'd check this list first to see if it's available to you. On my system, `Gotham` wasn't listed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can confidently confirm that changing the line `mainLabel.setFont(new Font("Gotham",18));` does indeed change the displayed font, at least in my environment (BlueJ). Are you making sure to compile so you're using the updated .class files?

Comment: I see, I now have moved all the code into a new project and tested and it is now working. There must have been something wrong with the Project structure. Thanks for confirming :D (Spent 2 hours thinking my code was the problem as I am a beginner)

Comment: Odd! When looking what was wrong I got the same error, the font just wouldn't change. I restarted IntelliJ and it magically started working. Weird one!

Answer (score 0):

In past I had similar problem with fonts. My font was not installed on the system. After this I had to do one more thing: build the project again to refresh application cache. This solved problem for me.

Comment: How to remove cache? I am changing the `<Font name="Times New Roman"/>` But it is not being changed in the displayed GUI

Answer (score 0):

You are actually missing an argument where you say ...

```java
mainLabel.setFont(new Font("Gotham",18));
```

I believe it should be like this,

```java
Panel panel = new Panel();
Graphics g = panel.getGraphics();

Font myFont = new Font("Calibri", Font.PLAIN, 24);
g.setFont(myFont);
```

Note the Font.PLAIN , Font.BOLD should do the trick, but also changes it for the whole panel !

Don't forget to import the Graphics class appropriately.

Comment: You're looking at the wrong API. This is a JavaFX question; the `Font` in question is `javafx.scene.text.Font`. There is no `Panel` class in JavaFX.